# Enable or disable iOS Application feature based on the configuration for the ios whitelabeling project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on an `iOS project` where I want to `maintain different configuration` of the application to be used for different customers. Each build targeted to the specific customer would be having the app theme customised and set of features enabled/disabled as per the configuration.

The current method I am using is very cumbersome where I am managing this manually over Xcode by manually adding/deleting the files and assets for different customer. I want to automate this whole process by using Xcode build configuration, preprocessor macro and scripting. However I am not sure if some specific scenarios can be handled by these methods or not such as:

1. I am using `third party library` for some features and when I disable that feature for a customer, I want also the remove that library and its references or dependent code from my IOS source code at compile time. Is there a way we could achieve this?
   E.g. I am using firebase SDK for chatting and I do not want to including chatting feature for one of the client for the same app and for other client I want to include this.
2. Is it possible or is there a standard way of doing this and say my app has 8 features and I want to package 3 feature for client1, 6 features for client2 and all 8 features for client3, `can I automate this?`

Please provide me any suggestion for it, thanks in advance

Comment: don't include chatting library to target pods

Comment: Why? you guys are down voting this question, any reason please let know...!

Answer (score 0):

You could base your whitelabing changes on a combination of build configurations, build settings, info.plist, schemes, and build phases. I faced the same problem as you and found awesome example: https://github.com/ChrisAU/WhiteLabelled.

The author also wrote a post about it:

https://medium.com/better-programming/white-labelling-in-xcode-a5ad66f30a8a.

It might be really helpful for you.